# botframework on teams channel 1:1 Authentication AAD integrated

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm looking to connect my bot on teams channel but i didn't know the way to secure this for use only in our domains (organization).

I have test to look (authentication AAD) for the Azure Web App but it's doesn't work on teams or on webchat because the endpoint adresse it's not redirected.

I have test to implement AUTH card but it doesn't work on teams.

Note : I'm using botframework C# api BotBuilder 3.15.2.2

I have look other "ask" like : 
[AAD authentication in Microsoft teams for Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41014628/aad-authentication-in-microsoft-teams-for-bot-framework)

[Is it possible to access custom tabs in 1:1 chats in MS Teams?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50628780/is-it-possible-to-access-custom-tabs-in-11-chats-in-ms-teams)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-flow-bot

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-bot-AAD

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/authentication

https://tsmatz.wordpress.com/2016/09/06/microsoft-bot-framework-bot-with-authentication-and-signin-login/

Sincerely,
Pascal.

Edit : 
I have implemented the solution sugested by Adrian, below was a piece of C# code that implement this on the MessasController.cs (Post Function): 
Note ==> Adding access for localhost use

```
 //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090597/botframework-on-teams-channel-11-authentication-aad-integrated
 string tenantIdAAD = "";
 try
 {
     tenantIdAAD = activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>().Tenant.Id;
 }
 catch (Exception exception)
 {
     tenantIdAAD = "";
 }

 ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));

 if ([AAD_TenantID].TenantIdAAD.Equals(tenantIdAAD) || activity.ServiceUrl.StartsWith("http://localhost") )
 {
     await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog().LogIfException());
 }
 else
 {
     await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(activity.CreateReply("Access Denied"));
 }
```

Comment: By "for use only in our domains", do you mean that only users from your organization should be able to use your bot?

Comment: Thx for your response Adrian. 
Yes it's what i locking for only my teams organization can be use the bot. 
But in current way the bot can be use in all organization if you take mi APP_ID.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The incoming message contains information that you can use to identify the user. A message looks like this:

`{
    ...
    "from": {
        "id": "29:1XJKJMvc5GBtc2JwZq0oj8tHZmzrQgFmB39ATiQWA85gQtHieVkKilBZ9XHoq9j7Zaqt7CZ-NJWi7me2kHTL3Bw",
        "name": "Richard Moe",
        "aadObjectId": "ae361bee-9946-4082-99dc-6994b00ceebb"
    },
    "channelData": {
        "tenant": {
            "id": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47"
        }
    }
}`

The `channelData.tenant.id` identifies the organization (O365 tenant) that the user is part of, so you can look at that and reject messages that aren't from ones that you expect.

The message also has the AAD object ID of the sender in `from.aadObjectId`. The auth flow in the links above is useful if you need tokens to provide to other services so you can act on behalf of the user, but if all you need is the user's tenant and identity, the message has all you need.

(Remember to [authenticate the incoming request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) first, before trusting any information in the message.)

Comment: Thx Andrian. 
I think it's the only way todo this at this time ? 
I doesn't like to check the tenant id (change beetween all of our platforme) but for this time i'm looking to implement on this way. 

Thx you for all and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Thx Andrian. 
I think it's the only way todo this at this time ? In general facts i'm looking for a way to get my current Web ADFS/AAD authentication token ? 

I go to implement on this way because at this time my bot was using only on teams but in future i didn't think it's was a god way.Thx you for all and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "changes between all our platforms"? The tenant id is fixed for a given O365 tenant.

Comment: Currently, there's no way to get the user's AAD token automatically-- you have to get the user to go through a login experience (as described in the documentation links you posted above) to get an AAD id or access token. Just wondering: if you did have a token, what would you do with it?

Comment: Thx you Adrian. 
It's because in future we looking to open our bot in other channel (like directLine or WebChat) to integrated this on a authenticated ADFS WebSite.

Comment: Thx you Adrian, i have test this way and it's work fine.

Comment: Ah, got it--thanks for the clarification! For channels that don't already include the information you need in the message, you can lead the user through an auth flow to get an id token. For DirectLine and WebChat, I think you could also authenticate the user in the hosting app/webpage, and then include the identity info in the messages that you send over DirectLine/WebChat.