# AAD Blocking Bot

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, botframework

I am implementing a simple bot in the Microsoft BotFramework. I have it deployed on Azure. For a number of reasons, I wish to make the app-service that the bot is hosted on use AAD authentication. However, in doing so I seem to render the bot unusable.

---

**Here's my context**:

I have bot - let's call it *ChatBot*. I have my app service; *chatbot*.

The app deploys through Visual Studio Teams Services Git using a Build and Release, successfully.

I have my 'default.htm' file modified to display my bot on the webpage, using the script:

```
<span class="skype-button bubble" data-bot-id="MyBotID" data-color="#ffffff"></span>
<span class="skype-chat" data-bot-id="MyBotID" data-color-message="#ffffff" data-show-header="true" data-can-upload-file="false"></span>
```

This is taken from [Skype for Developers](https://dev.skype.com/webcontrol), with the BotID modified.

Without AAD enabled for the chatbot service, I **can** communicate with the  embedded chat-bot on my Azure Website, as expected. However, when I enable AAD, I am asked to log in (as I'd expect). Once the website loads, the bot appears as normal. The chat-window then loads the icon I have assigned to bot on Azure, and shows the name of the bot in the chat-window header. However, when I chat to the bot, it shows the 'bot is responding' message and then no message is ever received.

It's strange, because the loading of the icon + title seems to imply that a connection is established, but it is unable to receive messages from the user (or perhaps is able to receive, but unable to send?). When I disable AAD again for the app-service, I am able to get bot responses fine. So something to do with AAD is prohibiting a part of the communication.

Apologies if it is obvious, but am I missing something; does enabling AAD for an app service have implications for embedded scripts, or for enabling communication with a messaging endpoint?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**: I want to clarify that after testing, I can confirm that I am not able to send messages: the 'Test In Web Chat' option in Azure gives me a 'Error - retry?' message when I try to send a message, and my Channel's 'Recent Issues' reports a number errors saying:

> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code
>   Unauthorized

I'm clearly getting a 401 because AAD is not authenticating for the bot, despite the app service clearly authenticating. Why is this?

Comment: `AAD enabled for the chatbot service` Can you clarify more about what you did to enable AAD with your bot service?

Comment: Sure - I went to the App Service in Azure, then in the blade selected 'Authentication / Authorization '. I then enabled 'App Service Authentication' and Configured my AAD Authentication Provider with the Client ID and Issuer URL. I then change the 'Action to Take' from 'Allow Annoymous Requests (no action) to 'Log in with Azure Directory'. 
This is on the app-service that supports the bot; the bot has no authentication settings. I did try to set up OAuth2, but to no avail.

Comment: You can refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) to add authentication to your bot via Azure Bot Service.

Comment: Hi to have an SSO AAD auth with bot i think it's not posible at this time look post i have asked last month : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090597/botframework-on-teams-channel-11-authentication-aad-integrated

Comment: Sorry for my last comment i didn't seen wath is your problem. I have the same issue 1 week later cf. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4977 and  https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4953  all off my old bot working fine but news i was try to deploy doesn't work.